# How to count an amount of time from the last of a particular event, in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, timer, autosave

In my Angular app, I want to autosave the changes a user makes.

My strategy for doing this is that I want to autosave 20 seconds after the user stops making changes. That is, if he is actively editing, I want the timer to keep resetting itself until the final keystroke, when it is allowed to run its full 20 second course and trigger the autosave.

How can I maintain a clock in Angular that can be reset regularly and used to trigger a function?

Comment: I use this module to detect if the user is idle https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle

Comment: @Ronnie thanks for the great recommendation. Not sure I will use it here but it will certainly be useful in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at $timeout in angular, you could call this from a function that is attached to each input box via ng-change.  Cancel the promise and re-create it everytime ng-change is hit.

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <input type=text ng-model="theValue" ng-change="QueueAutoSave()" />

  </body>
```

SCRIPT:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.theValue = 'World';

  var autoSavePromise;

  $scope.QueueAutoSave=function(){
    $timeout.cancel(autoSavePromise);
    autoSavePromise=$timeout(function(){
      alert("saved!");
    }, 20000);
  }
});
```

working example:
[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/obcSoI3suFeTFTfMZLig)

Answer (score 0):

The limitation of the previous answer is that you will need to add a function for ng-change on every input component in your application. I have previously isolated this functionality in a single directive which is application wide, enclosing all angular templates, forms, etc. The directive uses the bind function to listen for mouse, key events to reset the $timer. The timer function could then invoke a function to save all data, if you have such a function. But perhaps you are saving each piece of data on an individual basis.